# How to do watch on ngModel when value binds from component Angular 2/5?

Tags: angular, watch

I have Estimate textbox. When I change the value of other textboxes, the value of Estimate textbox is getting updated.

I need to change the value of Estimate textbox manually as well. So I want to put some watch on Estimate textbox so that whenever its value gets a change I can apply some custom code.

Here is the code I tried:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges, IterableDiffers, DoCheck } from '@angular/core'; 

constructor(differs: IterableDiffers) { 
      this.differ = differs.find([]).create(null); 
} 

ngDoCheck() { 
      const change = this.differ.diff([this.estimateValue]); 
}
```

I got the following error:
[image]

In short, I want to do exactly like $watch in AngularJS.

Can someone please help how to do it in Angular 5?

TIA!

Comment: What you have tried? Could you please share your code?

Comment: Try creating a pipe

Comment: pipe is also not working with [(ngModel)]

Comment: @RameshRajendran - I have updated the code I tried in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try working with a Form.
in your component.ts :

```
yourForm : FormGroup;
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,) {

this.yourForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   textBox: [''], 
});
}
ngOnInit(){

    this.yourForm.controls['textBox'].valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
         //Do whatever you want with your val
    });    
}
```

In your Html :

```
<form [formGroup]="yourForm">
   <div>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="exemple" formControlName="textBox">
   </div>
</form>
```

Now anytime your textBox value changes, it fires an event with the value of the field inside the subscribe with the value "val".

Comment: Thanks @HMarteau! But then I could not able to do two way binding.

Comment: It is a correct answer to my question though! Thanks once again!